# Will this diagnosis from my cardiologist prevent me from getting a Class 1 JAA medical?

Tags: medical, ppl, cpl

In 3 days I will have my Class 1 JAA medical test for the first time. However I said let's do a heart checkup before I go there and when I did this suddenly my cardiologist wrote that I have:

> Anterior mitral leaflet is slightly redundant and shows mild systolic prolapse. Trivial mitral regurgitation present.

He did for me a TMT and my performance was 97% as I'm 23 years old my heart rate increased to 195 bpm.

He told me this will not affect your pilot studies and nothing to worry about because it is normal and if you want to check it again, check it after 4 years, however no need to check it again.

Now I'm worried, will they stop me if they found out about this or what will happen?

Comment: I have no idea what the heart issues are but let me tell you that nobody is ever 100% free of some sort of medical condition that isn't quite the norm. As long as you won't pass out at the controls you'll probably be fine. Make sure you tell the JAA because hiding it will be a bad look and could be grounds for cancellation. Let us know how the medical goes.

Comment: sure, i hide it or not whenever the doctor put his stethoscope on my chest he will know about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i passed my medical exam and it was good, this issue wasn't a big problem at all even its not a problem.